# java.time: How to validate calendar weeks

Tags: java, java-time

How to verify that a calendar week is valid?

For example:

- Week 53 in the week based year 2018 is not valid in the ISO-8601 calendar system. The year 2018 only has 52 calendar weeks.
- Week 53 in 2020 is valid - it is from 28. Dec 2020 until 03. Jan 2021. ("The first week of a week-based-year is the first Monday-based week of the standard ISO year that has at least 4 days in the new year" - [see IsoFields javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html))

How to figure this out via `java.time`?

Comment: Hum, all years have 52 weeks no ? Validate a whole date like 32/13/2555 ?

Comment: @azro no, there are years, that have 53 calendar weeks - for example 2020 in the ISO-8601 calendar system. Week 53 in 2020 is from 28. Dec 2020 until 03. Jan 2021.

Comment: @NengLiu The question you've linked is about getting the week number of a given date - I need validation, if a week for a certain year is existing.

Comment: @olivmir can you edit your question and show us some years that is valid and some that are not?

Comment: @YCF_L OK, I have added another example

Comment: @olivmir Sorry but I don't understand the second point **Week 53 in 2020 is valid - it is from 28. Dec 2020 until 03. Jan 2021.** how it is a valid year but it use two years `2020` and `2021`

Comment: @YCF_L To understand better, read the javadoc for IsoFields - I've added it in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`TemporalAccessor.range(TemporalField)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html#range-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 1);
ValueRange range = date.range(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR);
System.out.println(range.getMaximum());  // 53
```